# TestNG interceptTestClassConstructor analog

Tags: java, junit, testng

I need somehow to intercept Test class constructor to override a behavior. In `JUnit`, it is done with:

```java
@Override
public <T> T interceptTestClassConstructor(Invocation<T> invocation,
                                           ReflectiveInvocationContext<Constructor<T>> invocationContext,
                                           ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Throwable {
...
}
```

How is this achievable in TestNG?

Comment: Why do you need to override that? I believe TestNg constructs test class using default constructor. If you need to set up some fields you can use some DI frameworks. TestNg has native [support of Guice](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#guice-dependency-injection).

Comment: I'm trying to create some tests that are CDI aware, in JUnit I use this method to skip construction by JUnit and get the object from CDI. Like: 
        invocation.skip();
        return container.select(invocationContext.getExecutable().getDeclaringClass())
                .get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the behavior using `IObjectFactory`.

```java
public class CustomObjectFactory implements IObjectFactory {

    @Override
    public Object newInstance(Constructor constructor, Object... params) {
        if(constructor.getDeclaringClass().equals(YourTestCalss.class)) {
            return yourCustomObject();
        }

        try {
            return constructor.newInstance(params);
        } catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // error handling...
        }
    
        return null; // or any other object or throw exception
    }
}
```

Now in a test class, add a method as below:

```java
@Test
public class YourTestClass {
    // ......
    // test methods
    // ......


    @ObjectFactory
    public ITestObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new CustomObjectFactory();
    }
}
```

Please note that even though this method is declared inside `YourTestClass`, this same object factory would be used for every other test class in your suite. Hence the `if` condition to check the class is required in `CustomObjectFactory.newInstance`.

You may also try `IObjectFactory2` which has a `newInstance` method taking `Class` as the parameter.

---

TestNG has an implementation for `IObjectFactory` -> `ObjectFactoryImpl`.
You could use `extends ObjectFactoryImpl` instead, in which case the code within the `newInstance could be:

```java
if(constructor.getDeclaringClass().equals(YourTestCalss.class)) {
    return yourCustomObject();
}
return super.newInstance(constructor, params);
```

**BUT note that, Since `ObjectFactoryImpl` is inside the `testng.internal` package, I assume that extending `ObjectFactoryImpl` is not recommended.**

Answer (score 1):

As discuss in [mailing group](https://groups.google.com/g/testng-users/c/CoFEnZTWDJM), @KrishnanMahadevan fixed a [bug](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2676) which will allow to intercept Test class constructor in version 7.5

> ```
> public class LocalSuiteAlteringListener implements IAlterSuiteListener {
> @Override
> public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
>    suites.forEach(each -> each.setObjectFactoryClass(MyFactory.class));
> ```